# MySQL - Grouping results from three tables with a shared key

Tags: mysql

I am trying to group results from three different tables with a shared key.

In my database I have three tables from three teams - `teamone, teamtwo, teamthree`

Then I have another table that is called `league` to which these teams belongs.
The league table has two `columns id, leaguename`

Each team table has the `columns id, league_id, team_name, team_function - and other columns specific` to the team

The reason I have three tables for three teams is because besides the first four columns all other columns are different due to some business reasons and the data cannot be stored in the same table.

I am trying to build a query that will do the following:

List all the leagues

```
- Display all the teams associated with each league.
```

I tried various join and union options but couldn't make it work. Any suggestion would be great.

Comment: Share what you have tired + share the `show create table <table_name> code` + sample input + expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This Query

```
SELECT l.leaguename, t1.team_name, t2.team_name, t3.team_name 
 FROM league l 
 INNER JOIN teamone t1 ON l.id = t1.league_id
 INNER JOIN teamtwo t2 ON l.id = t2.league_id  
 INNER JOIN teamthree t3 ON l.id = t3.league_id
```

OR

```
SELECT l.leaguename, t1.team_name, t2.team_name, t3.team_name 
 FROM league l 
 LEFT JOIN teamone t1 ON l.id = t1.league_id
 LEFT JOIN teamtwo t2 ON l.id = t2.league_id  
 LEFT JOIN teamthree t3 ON l.id = t3.league_id
```

I believe `LEFT JOIN` provide accurate result. But Try both and check.